# Nginx location - sites configuration not working after change location

Tags: nginx, pgadmin-4

i have setup pgadmin on ubuntu server, nginx conf is like below and works fine, example.com/:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;
        include proxy_params;
    }

}
```

but i want to access to pgadmin with /pgadmin4/ and i change block server to below and not work, example.com/pgadmin4/:

```
server {
    ...
    location /pgadmin4/ {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;
        include proxy_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

i have added this line to location /pgadmin and works fine:

```
location /pgadmin {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin;
}
```